# get data from arduino using python

Tags: arduino-mega, python

I am trying to **read potential meter data from Arduino using python**, with the program on Arduino as follows :

```
#include <cvzone.h>

SerialData serialData;
int sendVals[2];

void setup() {
  serialData.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int potVal = analogRead(A0);
  sendVals[0]= potVal;
  serialData.Send(sendVals);
}
```

the program on the arduino side is running fine

and program in python as follows

```
from cvzone.SerialModule import SerialObject

arduino = SerialObject("COM7")

while True:
   data = arduino.getData()
   print(data[0])
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    data = arduino.getData()
  File "C:...\site-packages\cvzone\SerialModule.py", line 68, in getData
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How to solve it?

Comment: the new USB connection resets the Mega and it spends some time in bootloader waiting for upload.

Comment: Maybe add some delay on the Arduino after initializing the serialData in `startup()`  before it starts sending data in the `loop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would embed the call to `.getData()` into a `try` block and handle this specific exception with `except UnicodeDecodeError`. There can always be a transmission error, especially when the script is started.

However, I would do it differently:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
```

...and on the python side use `serial.readline()` from pyserial instead.
But I don't know cvzone and you might have a reason to use this instead of the commonly used pyserial.

Comment: thank you very much, this really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems that there *may* be an issue with the implementation of `getData()` in [`SerialModule.py`](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/cvzone/SerialModule.py).

From [line 62](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/cvzone/SerialModule.py#L67)

```python
    def getData(self):
        """
        :param numOfVals: number of vals to retrieve
        :return: list of data received
        """
        data = self.ser.readline()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        data = data.split('#')
        dataList = []
        [dataList.append(d) for d in data]
        return dataList[:-1]
```

The block of code containing the `readLine()` should probably be with in a `try...except` block, like so:

```python
    def getData(self):
        """
        :param numOfVals: number of vals to retrieve
        :return: list of data received
        """
        try:
            data = self.ser.readline()
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            data = data.split('#')
            dataList = []
            [dataList.append(d) for d in data]
            return dataList[:-1]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.ser.close
```

An issue has been raised on Github: [SerialModule.py - readLine() should be within try block. #49](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/issues/49)